# How to use multiple account in GAS with OAuth2?

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-drive-api

I followed the GAS [OAuth2 library example](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/Google.gs). But I want to achieve the following.

1. UserA request to GAS for [authorizationUrl](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2#2-direct-the-user-to-the-authorization-url) through Https get/post request (`doGet()` or `doPost()`) with a parameter userID
2. GAS returns the **authorizationUrl** and save its `state` variable in Google Sheet with UserA's userID
3. UserA authorizes with using that **authorizationUrl**
4. GAS checks the `state` variable from the [`authCallback()`](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2#3-handle-the-callback) function and verifies it with the old stored `state` variable from the google sheet. If it is same, then store UserA's **Access Token** with userID in the same google sheet

Something like this

```
function authCallback(request) {
  var service = getService();
  var authorized = service.handleCallback(request);
  var state = request.parameter.state;
  if (authorized) {
    if(state == getOldState(userID)){
      storeToken(userID, service.getAccessToken());
    }
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<h1>Success!</h1>');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied.');
  }
}
```

5. Now UserA can modify his drive with Https request to the GAS and GAS control UserA's drive with saved **Access Token**
6. UserB request for authorizationUrl
7. GAS also returns authorizationUrl to UserB and he can also access GAS.
8. GAS also save UserB's access token with his userID.
9. Now GAS can control both UserA's and UserB's drive with their userID and already saved **Access Token.**

Is it possible?  I know the access token expires after some time. Please help me to complete my hobby project

Comment: I guess it's possible, but I think it'll be easier to just use a [tag:google-apps-script-web-application] set to execute as "user accessing"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `PropertiesService` class.

Example:

In your script's `doPost()` save the access token, and refresh token into a user specific property.

The script will be able to fetch these properties using the same `PropertiesService`.

**Further reading:**

- [PropertiesService class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)
- [Apps script Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)

Comment: Can you explain? Or give me any tutorial

Comment: can you share your WhatsApp, Telegram, Facebook, or any social media link?

Comment: I recommend you take a look at the Apps script services, and what you can do with them. Because you can deploy a script as a web-app and use all those services on behalf of the user who visits it, provided your app asks the user to authorize the required scopes. Have a look at extending G Suite with [Add-Ons built with Apps script](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview)